# Easiest way to read a txt file(with char and numbers) into a numerical array/matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, text-files

really frustrated with this one problem. Basically there is a txt file that has lines of code, code being a mixture of letters and numbers (of different length) WITHOUT commas and spaces in between them ie: one code from the txt file is X32W21039A23

I need to read it into an numerical array/matrix so that it will be easy for me to manipulate it, AND I have to replace the letters with their corresponding numbers from a table. This is what I currently have

```
fid = fopen('upcs.txt');
mat = [];
if fid == -1
disp('File open was not successful')
else 
while feof(fid) == 0
    % Read contents of file and store into a matrix
    aline = fgetl(fid);
    [P] = sscanf(aline, '%s');
    if length(A) == 12
        mat = [mat P];
    end
end
codes =reshape(mat, length(mat)/12, 12)
```

Basically I have removed all the lines from the txt file that were not 12 figures long (I can do that), and transferred the remaining lines into a character array, 'mat'. However, mat is a character array, not a numerical one. I've tried such functions as cell2mat and str2num, but to no avail, for I believe the codes are treated as cells or strings, rather than numbers. I believe I need to put spaces between the strings in the array.

So to sum up, can anyone help me easily transfer the codes in the txt file into a manner such that I can easily manipulate it like a vector of numbers ie: [1 2 3] thanks

Comment: I believe your problem is `sscanf(aline, '%s')`. You are reading strings. Just change to `%d` of `%f` and you'll get numbers in P.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I need to put spaces between the strings in the array".  What actually is your problem?  Characters still behave as numbers do you can still do arithmetic or indexing operations.

Comment: Say one of the codes in the txt file is X32W21039A23 and I need to replace the letters with the number -2. If I do the above script, and replace the X with a -2 with the command codes(1) = -2, I just get a blank for the code. it would look like this ' 32W21039A23'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but you can force MATLAB to store a matrix as a number by converting it to a `double`:

```
codes = double(codes)
```

However, you can still perform arithmetic and indexing operations etc. with characters, so I'm not sure if that does anything you couldn't already do for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if I do codes =double(codes), the code actually changes, ie: 074407986439 becomes 48    55    52    52    48    55    57    56    54    52    51    57, but I want to keep the numbers of 074407986439. I get message "Warning: Out of range or non-integer values truncated during conversion to
character. "

Comment: I didn't really understand what you were asking - if you want to convert number characters to their integer equivalents, you would use `str2num`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do, however there are 2 problems. (1) There are no spaces between the number characters, but I want them to be so that it doesn't read string '44444' to number 44444 but 4 4 4 4 4 (2) somestrings have a letter in them, that I need to replace with the number -1, but not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
fid = fopen('upcs.txt');
mat = [];
if fid == -1
    disp('File open was not successful')
else 
    while feof(fid) == 0
        % Read contents of file and store into a matrix
        aline = fgetl(fid);
        P = sscanf(aline, '%d');
        if length(A) == 12
            mat = [mat; P];
        end
    end
end

codes = mat
```

Changed `sscanf` format to `%d`. Also changed `mat` appending. That way `mat` is already your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table of correspondance between ASCII characters read from your file and the values you want:

```
table = [zeros(1,'0'-1) , 0:9 , zeros(1,'A'-'9'-1) , ('A':'Z')-'A' + 10];
                                                   %// 10 -> 35
                                                   %// or whatever values for 'A' to 'Z'

table('0123456789ABCDWXYZ')
%// = [0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  32  33  34  35]

table('X32W21039A23')
%// = [33  3  2  32  2  1  0  3  9  10  2  3]
```